# Reading from a jagged array

Tags: c++

I'm currently working with jagged arrays and I have a few questions regarding them. My class currently reads a txt file and then transverses that data into an output file.

Note: My class is not working with vectors so please don't provide code involving them. I know they are more efficient/simpler (at least that's what I read) but I'm not at that level yet. Also, writeJaggedArrayToFile is empty, that is because I haven't done anything with it yet.

Currently, I'm using "inputF >> rowIndex >> temp >> rowLen >> temp;" to access the row index and column length. Temp is used as a filler variable to ignore the "#"'s. Is there a way to extract the data without creating a variable like temp and filling up memory. I've tried creating strings with getline() but the # isn't a delimiter between every number and then I would have to reconvert the numbers back into integers rather than strings.

Also, my professor gave us a few lines of code such as:

```
int **A = new int*[numRow];
numColumns = new int[numRow];
```

I do not fully understand how these work. new int is being used as a pointer I believe but how?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ReadAndWriteJaggedArray {

private:

    int numRow; // the number of rows in the jagged array, update this when 
you read the file
    int *numColumns; // the number of columns in each row of the jagged array, update this when you read the file

public:

    ~ReadAndWriteJaggedArray() {
    delete numColumns;
    }

    int **fileJaggedArray() {
        numRow = 0;
        ifstream inputF;
        inputF.open("jaggedArrayInput.txt");

        if(!inputF.is_open()){
            cout << "Error: Unable to open file." << endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        inputF >> numRow;

        int **A = new int*[numRow];
        numColumns = new int[numRow];

        for(int i=0;i<numRow;i++){
            int rowIndex;
            int rowLen;
            char temp;

            inputF >> rowIndex >> temp >> rowLen >> temp;
            numColumns[rowIndex] = rowLen;
            A[rowIndex] = new int[rowLen];

            for(int j=0;j<rowLen;j++){
            inputF >> A[rowIndex][j];
            }
        }

        inputF.close();
        return A;
    }

    void writeJaggedArrayToFile(int **A) { 

    }
};

int main() {
    ReadAndWriteJaggedArray jaf;
    int **jaggedArray = jaf.fileJaggedArray();
    jaf.writeJaggedArrayToFile(jaggedArray);
    delete jaggedArray;
    return 0;
}
```

The text file that I'm using:

```
6
0 # 3 # 5 7 1
1 # 2 # -14 9
2 # 4 # 9 1 0 4
3 # 1 # -27
4 # 5 # 9 10 -7 45 12
5 # 4 # 99 1 14 -881
```

Comment: Yo, the paradigmatic, C++ way is to use `std::vector<std::vector<`

Comment: Do you wanna learn pointers or implement jagged arrays?

Comment: Implement jagged arrays

Answer (score -1):

Here is a quick example of a more paradigmatic way to deal with jagged data.

Notice that the size of each column is stored in the actual `std::vectors`. Rather than the non-paradigmatic, and bug prone C way of keeping the container (a pointer) in sync with the expected size.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
std::vector<std::vector<int>> jagged_data;

int main()
{
    auto rows = 9;
    for (auto row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
    {
        jagged_data.push_back(std::vector<int>());
        jagged_data[row].resize(row, row);
    }
    jagged_data.back().resize(4);//mess up the last one as an example.
    for (const auto& row : jagged_data)
    {
        for (const auto& data_at_column : row)
        {
            std::cout << data_at_column << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Prints

```
1
2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5
6 6 6 6 6 6
7 7 7 7 7 7 7
8 8 8 8
```